# how to call function in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

i am a beginner. So please bear with me. i have a domain class and one controller and one service. i have created two method; one to get the list and other is to get the parameter and return the parameter to check that it accepts value. but i dont know how to call the function. As i ever type localhost:8080/projectname/controllername/methodname. it returns 404 view not found.
Here is the code
package is testone

Domain:ReadData.groovy

```
package testone
import grails.rest.*;
class ReadData {
String customername;
    String fathername;
    static constraints = {
        customername blank: false;
        fathername blank:false;
    }
}
```

Controller:ReadDataController.groovy

```
package testone

import grails.converters.JSON

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ReadDataController {

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    def ReadDataService readDataService;

    def index(Integer max) {

        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond ReadData.list(params), [status: OK]
    }


    @Transactional
    def save(ReadData readDataInstance) {
        if (readDataInstance == null) {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }

        readDataInstance.validate()
        if (readDataInstance.hasErrors()) {
            render status: NOT_ACCEPTABLE
            return
        }

        readDataInstance.save flush:true
        respond readDataInstance, [status: CREATED]
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(ReadData readDataInstance) {
        if (readDataInstance == null) {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }

        readDataInstance.validate()
        if (readDataInstance.hasErrors()) {
            render status: NOT_ACCEPTABLE
            return
        }

        readDataInstance.save flush:true
        respond readDataInstance, [status: OK]
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(ReadData readDataInstance) {

        if (readDataInstance == null) {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }

        readDataInstance.delete flush:true
        render status: NO_CONTENT
    }
    def readList(){
        readDataService.testList();
    }
    def getName(String name){
        render name;
    }
}
```

Service: ReadDataService.groovy

```
package testone

import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class ReadDataService {

    def serviceMethod() {

    }
    def testList(){
        return ReadData.list();
    }
}
```

bootstrap:

```
import testone.ReadData

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
         new ReadData(customername: 'NameOne',fathername: 'FnameOne').save();
        new ReadData(customername: 'NameTwo',fathername: 'FnameTwo').save();

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

please help me in calling these function or tell me the way to consume services method directly. I want to use grails services in android app.

Comment: How are you calling your controller? Can you include the exact URL you are using (pay attention to CaPiTaLiZaTiOn) and any HTTP headers that you are sending?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/TestOne/readData/readList

Comment: The controller class definition should be `class ReadDataController extends RestfulController {`

Answer (score 0):

You sure, you've created a view for **readList** method?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a list back from you controller `readList` action . Try passing a map like

```
['testList':readDataService.testList()]
```

and also as the previous person said check if you have a view. Otherwise if you want to pass JSON to your android app you should add

```
 render readDataService.testList() as JSON
```

at the end of your `readList` action.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up the method allowed to be called in:
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
basically method

- save will be available by a post (form submission e.g.)
- update will be available by http PUT method (not available in a browser)
- delete avalaible by a DELETE method (same as before)

So you should add all methods that you want to call e.g.

allowedMethods = [readList:["GET","POST"],save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

ref.: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html